# SQL Substitute value based on same field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am trying to evaluate how long a user is potentially online for.

Below is the data structure I am working with.

| Name | Date | Time | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-01-01 | 10:00 | Log-On |
| John | 2022-01-01 | 11:00 | Log-Off |
| John | 2022-01-02 | 09:00 | Log-Off |
| John | 2022-01-03 | 15:00 | Log-On |

I am using the following logic:

- When the Log-On time is not provided, use the Log-Off time.
- When the Log-Off time is not provided, use the Log-On time.
- I am taking the MIN LogOn time for a particular day.
- I am taking the MAX LogOff time for a particular day.

Below is the expected Outcome:

| ID | Name | Date | MinLogOnTime | MaxLogOffTime | TimeDifferenceHr ( Max - Min Time) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-01 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 1 |
| 2 | John | 2022-01-02 | 09:00 | 09:00 | 0 |
| 3 | John | 2022-01-03 | 15:00 | 15:00 | 0 |

Below is a query that I having been trying, but with no luck yet:

```
SELECT      [Name]
            ,[Date]
            ,ISNULL(LogOn, MIN(CASE WHEN [Event] IN ('Log-Off') THEN [Time] ELSE NULL END)) AS MinLogOnTime
            ,ISNULL(LogOff, MAX(CASE WHEN [Event] IN ('Log-On') THEN [Time] ELSE NULL END)) AS MaxLogOffTime
            ,DATEDIFF(HH, ISNULL(LogOff, MAX(CASE WHEN [Event] IN ('Log-Off') THEN [Time] ELSE NULL END)), ISNULL(LogOn, MIN(CASE WHEN [Event] IN ('Log-On') THEN [Time] ELSE NULL END)) AS 'TimeDifferenceHr ( Max - Min Time)'

FROM        (
            SELECT          [Name]
                            ,[Date]
                            ,[Event]
                            ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Event] IN ('Log-On') THEN [Time] ELSE NULL END) AS LogOn 
                            ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Event] IN ('Log-Off') THEN [Time] ELSE NULL END) AS LogOff 
            GROUP BY        [Name], [Date], [Event]
            ) x
GROUP BY    [Name], [Date]
ORDER BY    [Name], [Date]
```

I would really appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: If someone logs on twice in a row, and then logs off later, what would you expect?

Comment: Hi @Larnu. I would take the MIN logon time for that day, and the MAX logoff for that day.

Comment: So you just want the `MIN` and `MAX` now? So someone that logs on at 09:00, logs off at 10:00, and then logs on again at 16:00 and off at 17:00 would have a value of 8 hours (even though they were only really logged in for 2 hours)?

Comment: Hi @Larnu. Yes, for now it would just be the MIN and MAX for the day. The result would be 8 hours.

Comment: So what's wrong with a (conditional) `MIN` and `MAX`? Then you can just do `MAX` - `MIN`.

Comment: Still working my way up with SQL. I don't believe I am applying the logic correct, especially with using a LogOn time when a LogOff is not provided, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the comments, it seems you just need some conditional aggregation. As you *might* not have a On/Off for each day, then you need to get the `MIN`/`MAX` for both event types, and then you can use `ISNULL` (or `COALESCE`):

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Name,
           [Date],
           MIN(CASE Event WHEN 'Event' THEN [Time] END) AS MinLogOnTime,
           MAX(CASE Event WHEN 'Event' THEN [Time] END) AS MaxLogOnTime,
           MIN(CASE Event WHEN 'Event' THEN [Time] END) AS MinLogOffTime,
           MAX(CASE Event WHEN 'Event' THEN [Time] END) AS MaxLogOffTime
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY Name,
             [Date])
SELECT Name,
       Date,
       ISNULL(MinLogOnTime,MinLogOffTime) AS MinLogOnTime,
       ISNULL(MaxLogOffTime,MaxLogOnTime) AS MaxLogOffTime,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR,ISNULL(MaxLogOffTime,MaxLogOnTime),ISNULL(MaxLogOffTime,MaxLogOnTime)) AS TimeDifference
FROM CTE;
```